# Getting HiddenField value upon clicking the button

Tags: javascript, c#, xml

I want to get the value of the hiddenfield when clicking the button **BUT** from the parentNode of the button I just clicked.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="gameInfo">
     <input type="text" ID="gameTitle" disabled="disabled" />
     <input type="text" ID="gameType" disabled="disabled" />
     <input type="text" ID="gameprice" disabled="disabled" />
     <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Hiddenf">
     <input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onclick="myFunc(this)" />
</div>
</div>
```

so I have this javascript here which when clicked the button it gets the parent node of the button and enables all the fields in that parent div as you can see, any way I could incorporate it into this function? Also I would need to be able to get this value in the code behind once I have retrieved the value from the hidden field.

```
function myFunc(elm){
for( var inputs = elm.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')
  ,          L = inputs.length
  ; L--
  ; inputs[L].disabled = false  //enable inputs
  ); //end loop
}
```

Comment: What has this to do with c#. The code IS in a (pretty incomprehensible) function so what is your question?

Comment: Ricardos answer works... but by saying from the parentNode of the button you clicked, you are implying that there will be multiple gameInfo wrappers? Giving multiple hidden fields in one page with non unique IDs? You really should make your question more explciti... i.e. explain it better!

Comment: @BenRobinson I am using a asp.net hidden field and I want to get this in the code behind but firstly I need to get the value thought you would have realised that

Comment: @user2653531 the fact that you are using c# in your code behind is not relevant to the question you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant set the ID to be static, you have to look for it:

```
var value = elm.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=hidden][id$="HiddenF"]').value;
```

querySelector exists for any element, and will only look inside of it.

Comment: I will have another hiddenfield of the same ID in another div would I be able to distinguish between them both and get the right one that's the reason I was using parent node?